# Why isn't my WPF control's code-behind running at design time?

Tags: wpf, design-time

I have some code in my WPF `UserControl` constructor but it doesn't seem to be executed at design time.

I'm *sure* that code behind is supposed to run at design time, and there is plenty of sample code on StackOverflow showing people using design time checks which supports this being the case.

I have even tried attaching a debugger and the breakpoints doesn't get hit.

Comment: Without the code in question, it's hard to answer. [mcve]? I can tell you it should run (if it's in the constructor, the Loaded, Initialised or similar event handler. Click event will most likely be caught by the designer). **If you want to hit that breakpoint, you need to open another instance of Visual Studio and attach it to your design instance.** If that doesn't work either - show your code.

Comment: The code in question is essentially a default `UserControl` with a standard ctor containing `InitializeComponent` and then some custom code to set TextBox text. Irrespective the code isn't being run.

Comment: How can you tell? Are you overwriting properties, executing something like showing a message box, etc.?

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer yes I attached from another VS instance. I am familiar with debugging WPF design time :)

Answer (score 4):

I think I have found the answer in a [very old 2007 article on the WPF Designer](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jnak/2007/11/08/dont-do-that-in-the-wpf-designer-cider/) (known at the time as 'Cider'). Here is the important bit:

> When you write code behind for a particular control, that code behind
>   **may or may not be run at design time**.
>
> If the code behind is in the constructor of a control that is hosted
>   by a parent in the Cider designer, it will be run when that control is
>   loaded onto the design surface.  For instance, if I create a
>   UserControl named MyUserControl and place it on a Window, the
>   constructor for MyUserControl will be run when that Window is loaded
>   in Cider.
>
> However, if I am designing MyUserControl in Cider, because that type
>   is being modified and created at that time, we don’t instantiate
>   MyUserControl — which in turn means that none of the code behind for
>   MyUserControl will be run.

To verify this I created a new `UserControl1.xaml` and dropped in an instance of my control with code-behind, and the code-behind ran at design time as expected.